# React: Using one JavaScript function to change and target multiple ID's

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function

I have 1 JavaScript function that can change the position of my scroll tray and move left and right which works fine.

However, to use this function on each scroll tray (I have like 5 of them) I need to make 5 different slideRight and slideLeft functions (each with their own name) where I need to pass different ID's in document.getElementById. Is there a way to have only one slideLeft and slideRight function and that those function based on ID's can know which slider to turn left or right?

Something like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple except I do not have slide shows, rather a slider with images in one line.

```
export function slideRight() {
    let container = document.getElementById('scroll-tray-1')
    sideScroll(container, 'right', 25, 400, 40);
};

export function slideRight() {
    let container = document.getElementById('scroll-tray-2')
    sideScroll(container, 'left', 25, 400, 40);
};

function sideScroll(element, direction, speed, distance, step) {
    let scrollAmount = 0;
    var slideTimer = setInterval(function () {
        if (direction === 'left') {
            element.scrollLeft -= step;
        } else {
            element.scrollLeft += step;
        }
        scrollAmount += step;
        if (scrollAmount >= distance) {
            window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
        }
    }, speed);
}
```

I tried to follow the W3 Schools example but I was not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by passing the function parameters while invoking the function. The only difference is that when invoking the function with parameters in React, I had to invoke it like an arrow function '() => slider('scroll-tray', 'left')' in order for it to work.

Comment: Use code formatting option in editor; this makes answers and questions more readable